# Starting Camera Activity Cordova Plugin

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Basically, what I want to do is to create Aztec code reader plugin.
So I need to open some kind of camera screen inside my app. I should do that inside my Java code, which right now looks like so:

```
public class AztecReaderPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        try {
            if(action.equals("open")) {
                Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                callbackContext.success();
                return true;
            }
            callbackContext.error("Something gone wrong!");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It basically should execute the code inside `MainActivity` class. And the `MainActivity` class method `onCreate` looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnDoFocus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAutoFocus);
        btnDoFocus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.autoFocus();
            }
        });


        Button btnDoAztec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDoAztec);
        btnDoAztec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                preview.setEnableReadAztecCode(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

The thing is, when I did forget about `AztecReaderPlugin`, and run the `MainActivity` code as an standalone Android app, it works just like I would want.

I can't find any tutorial/post that would help me with my problem, and I don't have time to learn Android developing.

So my question is: How can I include that Aztec Code Reader inside my Cordova App?

// EDIT

I can Include my Plugin into App, the problem lays inside `AztecReaderPlugin` class and some Activity-related method. My problem is I can't open some kind of camera view through cordova. And that Camera view is my Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

Firstly you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml. You can found this file in res > xml folder.

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.Phonegap.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Then you need to implement plugin by using Java- code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally we calling a plugin from javascript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: That is not what I wanted to achieve. My problem is, I want to run some kind of Camera View inside Cordova plugin. But I think I did wrote something wrong.